# Try to build an analog clock,but its Hours hand is not working properly,Help me to solve Hours hand code

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, ecmascript-6

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.sec');
const minHand = document.querySelector('.min');
const hoursHand = document.querySelector('.hour');
function setDate(){
  const now = new Date();
 const seconds= now.getSeconds();
 const secondsDegree =((seconds /60) *360) + 90;
 secondHand.style.transform =`rotate(${secondsDegree}deg)`;
  
 const Mins= now.getMinutes();
 const minsDegree =((Mins /60) *360) + 90;
 minHand.style.transform =`rotate(${minsDegree}deg)`;

  const hours= now.getHours();
 const hoursDegree =((Mins /12) *360) + 90;
 hoursHand.style.transform =`rotate(${hoursDegree}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("sky.jpg");
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.face {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.clock {
    border: 9px solid red;
    width: 21rem;
    height: 21rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.hand {
 transition : all 0.05s;
 transform-origin: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
.hand.sec {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.82, 1.51);
}
.hand.hour {
    height: 3px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 8px;
    background-color: red;
}
.hand.min {
    color: black;
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 8px;
}
audio {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
<div class="face">
<div class="hand hour"> &nbsp;&nbsp; THIS HAND INDICATE THE HOURS</div>
<div class="hand min">&nbsp;&nbsp;THIS HAND INDICATE THE Minutes</div>
<div class="hand sec"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to build an analog clock with three hand of hours ,minute and Second. But the hours hand is not working properly.I think there are some problems with the calculation of hours hand.Help me out this problem.

You can also check the css property to solve this problem or change something on my code.

Comment: const hoursDegree =((Mins /12) *360) + 90; should you use hour to calculate this?

Comment: You should hide the clock until the function has run the first time to stop the initial jerk. Also, *setTimeout* doesn't run at exactly the specified interval, it will slowly drift and then jump 2 second instead of 1. Use setTimeout, and on each run calculate the time to just after the next full second for the following call.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few small modifications are needed.

Specifically:

```
const hoursDegree =(((hours%12)/12) *360.0) + 90;
```

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.sec');
const minHand = document.querySelector('.min');
const hoursHand = document.querySelector('.hour');
function setDate(){
    const now = new Date();
    const seconds= now.getSeconds();
    const secondsDegree =((seconds / 60.0) *360) + 90;
    secondHand.style.transform =`rotate(${secondsDegree}deg)`;
  
    const Mins= now.getMinutes();
    const minsDegree =((Mins / 60.0) *360) + 90;
    minHand.style.transform =`rotate(${minsDegree}deg)`;

    const hours= now.getHours();
    const hoursDegree =(((hours%12) / 12.0) *360) + 90;
    hoursHand.style.transform =`rotate(${hoursDegree}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("sky.jpg");
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.face {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.clock {
    border: 9px solid red;
    width: 21rem;
    height: 21rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.hand {
 transition : all 0.05s;
 transform-origin: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
.hand.sec {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.82, 1.51);
}
.hand.hour {
    height: 3px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 8px;
    background-color: red;
}
.hand.min {
    color: black;
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 8px;
}
audio {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
<div class="face">
<div class="hand hour"> &nbsp;&nbsp; THIS HAND INDICATE THE HOURS</div>
<div class="hand min">&nbsp;&nbsp;THIS HAND INDICATE THE Minutes</div>
<div class="hand sec"></div>
</div>
</div>
```